# How to find data-src of Img tag using Class Name

Tags: jquery, html

**I have found the half part of the code but I am not getting how to find the next half.**
 The thing is I am finding the div next to active class div, reason for this is I wanted to find out the data-src attribute of the img tag. I have done some part to find out the next div of current class **active**. Now using this how to find out the data-src attribute of next.

```
var daraSrc = $('div.active').next()[0];
console.log("Data Src found "+ daraSrc);
// Result of above console is 
   <div data-slide-number="1" class="item">
     <img data-src="http:img/00013562000265_ing_en.jpg" class="img-
      responsive">
   </div>
```

Now How to find out the data-src of result and append that to src attribute so that that image will get load dynamically. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dataSrc = $('div.active').next("div").find("img").attr("data-src");
console.log(dataSrc);
```

This will get you the data-src attribute of the image tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to get next element.

```
$('div.active').next("div").attr("data-src")
```